# Are there some bhajans particularly appropriate for mourning a loss?

Tags: gods, funeral

In Buddhism there are some sutra chanted typically at a funeral.
Hindu bhajans are more musical than mere sutra chanting, but are there some bhajan culturally linked to mourning the loss of a loved one?

I don't mean specifically something chanted at the funerals proper, but rather some religious song that could be listened to in private to accompany the sadness.

I suspect that in this spectrum the popular music genre is more developed than the religious one.

Comment: Garuda Purana is generally read after funerals , maybe you can take a look at it .

Comment: In Telugu states, the Bhagavad GIta rendering by Ghantasaala Venkateswara Rao is sometimes played at funerals.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion But playing Bhagavad Gita during funerals is condemned by many in the Telugu states itself.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Can you name some of the people who condemn this?

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Many orators and pandits do not encourage this practice. I hope you know about Chaganti Koteshwara Rao, Garikipati Narasimha Rao. They do it for a reason. Because Bhagavad Gita was played at funerals, people have come to opinion that it's a song to be played during a funeral. People are forgetting it's importance in spirituality.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma IMO, "People are forgetting Gita's spirituality due to being played at funerals",  should not be the reason to condemn playing of the Gita at funerals. Let Gita be played at funerals, but let its importance in normal life be also recognized.